# How can I prove that $(x)^{(x+1)} > (x + 1) ^x$ for integer values of $x$ by induction?

Tags: exponentiation, binomial-theorem

It is obvious that if $x \geq 3 $ the LHS will always be bigger. But how can I prove this by induction. I have tried using the binomial theorem for $(x+1)^x$ but I couldn't complete it. The result is always bigger than $2x^2$ but I can't determine an upper bound.

Comment: Is it $x^{(x+1)}\gt (x+1)^x $ ?

Comment: Yes, it is. I didn't write it properly.

Comment: Why must you use induction?

Comment: Is $x$ a natural number?

Comment: I just wanted to see if it is possible by induction.

Comment: It's not true for $x=1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$(x+1)^{x+2}=x^{x+1}\cdot\left(1+\frac1x\right)^{x+1}\cdot(x+1)=x^{x+1}\cdot\left(1+\frac1x\right)^x\cdot\frac{(x+1)^2}x$$$$(x+2)^{x+1}=(x+1)^x\cdot\left(1+\frac1{x+1}\right)^x\cdot(x+2)$$

Note that $1+\frac1x>1+\frac1{x+1}$ and $(x+1)^2>x\cdot(x+2)$, so we are done by induction (assuming you prove the base case $x=3$).